# jquery autocomplete, return results to separate layer

Tags: jquery-ui

Using jquery UI 1.8's autocomplete, is there any known way to take the results and return them to a different div element on the page, or to customize how they look upon return? I want to have the results show up in a list that can be interacted with, essentially.

Comment: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941280/how-to-return-jquery-autocomplete-result-to-the-separate-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a built in way to return the results to another location on the page. However, customizing how they look is quite straightforward, that is just a matter of applying CSS to the widget. The [Theming](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming) docs will explain all the detail.

I would suggest attaching an event handler to one of the events of the autocomplete (maybe search) and writing your own custom code to capture the results and move them to the the required place in the DOM.