# How to return jquery autocomplete result to the separate div?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527930/jquery-autocomplete-return-results-to-separate-layer) that to overwrite one of the autocomplete events. But can somebody please provide me with example how to do the same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `appendTo` option does indeed work as expected, and if you inspect at the DOM, the `<ul>` results element will be attached to the element. However, due to absolute positioning generated by jQueryUI, the list still *appears* directly under the `<input>`.

That said, you can override the internal `_renderItem` to directly append results to a completely different element, for example:

#### HTML

```
<input id="autocomplete"/>
<div class="test">Output goes here:<br/><ul></ul></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    search: function(event, ui) {
        $('.test ul').empty();
    },
    source: ["something", "something-else"]
}).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {

    return $('<li/>')
   .data('item.autocomplete', item)
   .append(item.value)
   .appendTo($('.test ul'));
};
```

I have also created a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uMqyn/1/) to demonstrate this. Please note that the latest jQuery library has not had jQueryUI tested against it fully, so I am using the previous version which allows me to select to include jQueryUI directly with the jsFiddle options.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is what I am looking for - will test it more ;)

Comment: It seems that the SELECT handler that would usually fire when one selects an autocomplete option doesn't work with this setup. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Correct. Since the options have been pushed to a different element, none of the jQueryUI events will be fired. You would need to duplicate the events on your custom output element to mimic the jQueryUI autocomplete events and that just seems wrong. You could force the jQueryUI element to a new position which would retain the events which might work for you.

Comment: Awesome! It will be really useful for me as I am trying to use Geonames web service with jQuery Mobile. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

```
<div class="test">Output goes here:<br/></div>

<script>
  $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["something", "something-else"],
    appendTo: ".text",
    position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: ".test" }
// other options here
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work for me somehow - `$( "#search" ).autocomplete({ appendTo: ".test", source: "/search", minLength: 2});` What can be wrong here?

Comment: do you have a div with a `class="test"`?

Comment: Surely. I've tried this here - http://jsfiddle.net/Gn2dX/, it doesn't work also ((.

Comment: `autocomplete` is part of `jquery-ui`. Try to load that file after jquery. 
Your example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gn2dX/2/ 
jquery-ui: http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: jquery-ui surely works. And it is loaded after jquery ui in my code, so it doesn't help...

Comment: but it wasn't in the jsfiddle you sent me. did you try my example? http://jsfiddle.net/Gn2dX/2/

Comment: Yes, I am testing your example and it doesn't work for me (tried both with FF and Chrome).

Comment: Ok. That's strange. As soon as I write the letter 's' in the field it gives me the 2 words.

Comment: But is the result attached to 'test' class field? See here what happens on my PC - http://habrastorage.org/storage1/ccc5cb70/c4860d67/3b37b2bb/3216bf35.png (I've added a few br's).

Comment: Yes, it works now, but this is not what I am looking for - once user types something into search field, I want to display results in the separate field (like Google live search works now, but I don't need this dropdown with options - I need search results).

Comment: I like this answer in conjunction with the _renderItem solution. Works great for me. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

I needed more control over where to put the data, so this is how I went about it:

```
$("#input").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp"
    ],
    response: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.content);
        // put the content somewhere
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        // close the widget
        $(this).autocomplete('close');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

hle's answer worked awesome for me and gives you more flexibility! Here is my test code that was modified by his answer:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: ["something", "something-else"],
    response: function(event, ui) 
    {
        console.log(ui.content);
        // put the content somewhere
    },
    open: function(event, ui) 
    {
        // close the widget
        $(this).autocomplete('close');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is pretty old but i got a pretty easy solution. No hack, nothing just in jQuery way:

Instead of **autocomplete response function**, just add **response data** in div on success

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#book-code-search").autocomplete({
      minLength: 2,
      delay: 500,
      source: function (request, response) {
       $.ajax( {
        url: "server side path that returns json data",
        data: { searchText: request.term, param2 : $("#type").val()},
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( data ) {
          $("#data-success").html(data.returnedData); //returnedData is json data return from server side response
          /* response($.map(data, function (item) {
               return {
              label: item.FullDesc,
              value: item.FullDesc                      
             }
          })) */
        }
      });
     }
    });
   });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id='data-success' style='color: green;'></div>
<input type='text' placeholder='Enter Book Code' id='book-code-search' />
<input type='hidden' id='type' value='book'>
```